# Reactionless propulsion method (not physics heresy!?)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics, centrifugal-force, propulsion

**Description of process:** 
water or some other low viscosity fluid is rotated in a cone by an impeller or other means, and then ejected tangentially at the point where it climbs the highest (due to centrifugal force) or has the greatest angular momentum. The high speed fluid exits the funnel tangentially toward a splash plate, where it imparts momentum to a vehicle body. There are two of these cones positioned side by side to cancel out any centrifugal imbalances. Also the fluid quickly redistributes itself due to said force imbalances and its low viscosity. Both eject the fluid at the same target. The fluid is then collected and pumped back into the centre of the cone. I cant see why this would not work, can anyone more skilled in dynamic analysis see any flaws?? Thanks.
Just a note, The red tubes in the picture need to be lower down and attached to the funnel, also the funnels would not rotate, only the impellers.
[image]

Comment: A picture or two might help.

Comment: Your impellers provide momentum to the fluid. If you let that go you have a (poor) jet propulsion system. If you hit something you just cancel out that momentum. You have to analyze the whole system.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to picture exactly what you're describing, but it doesn't matter.

Whatever process you use to give the water momentum, the vehicle loses that momentum when the water leaves. When it hits the splash plate, it gives that momentum back. So you didn't gain anything.

With any physical process, the center of mass of the vehicle moves with a constant velocity. So, if there's nothing leaving the vehicle, the vehicle can't have any average acceleration.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, I am making a CAD model of this, but its not ready to display here, sorry. What you are saying is totally makes sense for linear acceleration like with a rocket, but the fluid is accelerated angularly so there would be no 'backwards' momentum right? Just a reverse torque on the impeller or fluid acclerator

Comment: @BruceWayne That's incorrect. There is a backwards momentum, because the fluid is not only accelerated angularly. If it were only accelerated angularly, it wouldn't leave the funnel.

Comment: @BruceWayne A funnel exerts a pressure on the fluid within it normal to the surface. Since the funnel is cone-shaped, this involves a component of force in the angular direction but also a component of force towards the "big" end of the funnel.